# ERROR in Cannot find name and implicity has any type

Tags: reactjs

The following error appears:

```
ERROR in src/components/Tasks.tsx:6:2

TS2552: Cannot find name 'Task'. Did you mean 'Tasks'?
    4 | return(
    5 |         <>
  > 6 | {Task.map((task) => (
      |  ^^^^
    7 | <h3 key={task.id}>{task.text}</h3>
    8 | )) }
    9 |
```

```
ERROR in src/components/Tasks.tsx:6:12

TS7006: Parameter 'task' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    4 | return(
    5 |         <>
  > 6 | {Task.map((task) => (
      |            ^^^^
    7 | <h3 key={task.id}>{task.text}</h3>
    8 | )) }
    9 |
```

Tasks.tsx code:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Tasks = () => {
return(
        <>
{Task.map((task) => (
<h3 key={task.id}>{task.text}</h3>
)) }

        </>
    )
}


export default Tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer, in the App.tsx is the following defined:

```
    import { useState } from 'react'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Tasks from './components/Tasks'

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
            {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Audit mit Lieferanten Schäffler durchführen',
        day: 'Feb 28th at 2:30 pm',
        reminder: true,
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Eskalation bei der Firma Balluff',
        day: 'Feb 6th at 1:30 pm',
        reminder: true,
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Lieferantengespräch mit ADE durchführen',
        day: 'Feb 5th at 2:30 pm',
        reminder: false,
        },
])

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Header />
      <Tasks />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).